# Excel IF returning 'FALSE' rather than cell reference

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to write an IF statement that returns a cell reference, and have entered the following statement:
=IF(B125="1",E124)
(I'm using several other IF criteria in the same formula, but it is the same result with just this) 
I'm getting a FALSE result instead of the cell E124 I want.
I have similar statements throughout the spreadsheet that do return the cell. I've tried deleting the rows, but still getting this result when I create again.
Any ideas?
Thank-you very much for your help.

Comment: What is supposed to happen when the result is false?  What is in B125, and is it text or numeric?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your current formula it will be looking in B125 for "1" and not 1; it is looking for a text string and not a number.

Unless B125 is populated by, or returning, a text string it won't match.

Comment: This does work - thank-you! Mysteriously, all my other formula ARE in the format I originally put with "1" and also work, but I'm not going to worry about why - it works and that's what matters!